# Create new column with values that I conditionally labelled

Tags: pandas, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I created a conditional statement that compares IDs in time windows and labels them according to their vector lengths. The following code creates a column 'intera':

```
time = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3])
ids = np.array([3271,3229,4228,2778,4228,3271,3229,3229,4228,2778,4228,3271,4228,3229,3271])
vec_len = np.array([,0.1,0.5,-0.0,0.0,0.1,-0.7,-0.3,-0.8,-0.6,0.2,0.1,-0.7,-0.3,-0.8])
quad = np.array([7,0,0,5,0,6,5,2,5,5,0,6,5,2,5])

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'id': ids, 'vec_len': vec_len, 'id': ids})
df['intera'] = np.array(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'id': ids, 'vec_len': vec_len, 'id': ids})
grp = df.groupby(['time', 'id'], as_index=False)
quant_25 = grp.vec_len.quantile(.25).rename(columns={'vec_len': 'quantile_2 5'})
quant_75 = grp.vec_len.quantile(.75).rename(columns={'vec_len': 'quantile_75'})

quantiles = pd.merge(quant_25, quant_75, on=['time', 'id'])
df = df.merge(quantiles, on=['time', 'id'])
df.loc[:, 'intera'] = df[['vec_len', 'quantile_25', 'quantile_75']].apply(
lambda x: 1 if x[0] < x[1] or x[0] > x[2] else 0, axis=1)
```

THis creates the interaction column:

```
time   id   vec_len  quadrant   interaction  

1    3271    0.9    7   0 
1    3229    0.1    0   0
1    4228    0.5    0   0
1    2778   -0.3    5   0
2    4228    0.2    0   0
2    3271    0.1    6   0
2    3229    -0.7   5   1    
2    3229    -0.3   2   0
2    4228    -0.8   5   1    
2    2778   -0.6    5   1    
3    4228    0.2    0   0
3    3271    0.1    6   0
3    4228    -0.7   5   1    
3    3229    -0.3   2   0
3    3271    -0.8   5   1
```

How can I create another column that shows the pairs or groups of IDs that are commonly assigned with 1 in the 'intera' column?

Expected column ("paired/grouped with")

```
time   id   vec_len  quadrant   interaction    Paired with

1    3271    0.9    7   0 
1    3229    0.1    0   0
1    4228    0.5    0   0
1    2778   -0.3    5   0
2    4228    0.2    0   0
2    3271    0.1    6   0
2    3229    -0.7   5   1    [2778, 4228]
2    3229    -0.3   2   0
2    4228    -0.8   5   1    [2778, 3229]
2    2778   -0.6    5   1    [4228, 3229]
3    4228    0.2    0   0
3    3271    0.1    6   0
3    4228    -0.7   5   1    [3271]
3    3229    -0.3   2   0
3    3271    -0.8   5   1    [4228]
```

Comment: Im sorry, how would the expected output look like?

Comment: `time=1` has 4 `id`s, but you pick only either 1 or 2 `id`s on each `interaction=1`. Could you explain the logic of picking them?

Comment: Hi andy, thanks for helping. I basically count the ids with interaction =1 in the same time block, and would want to create a new column with the IDs that are also equal to 1 in the same time block. Is this understandable?